# Retrieve mp3 file from cache and play it in browser

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, web-audio-api

I have an mp3 file that I am caching as such:

```
const request = URL_TO_MY_MP3_FILE
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
   cache.add(request);
});
```

I can see that the mp3 file is being cached in the Application tab:
[image]

By the way, how do I ensure that file is Content-Type cached as `audio/mp3` and not `audio/mpeg`?

Later on, I would like to retrieve the mp3 file from cache so I can play it in the browser:

```
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
 const responsePromise = cache.match(request);
 responsePromise.then(result => {
    console.log(result.body)
    this.audio = new Audio(result.body);

    const playPromise = this.audio.play();
      playPromise.then(function() {
         console.log('success!')
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
      }.bind(this), false);
 });
```

})

This is the output of `console.log(result.body)`:
[image]

After loading the mp3 file with `new Audio(result.body)` I try to play the file with `this.audio.play()` but this results in an error:

> DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

How can I retrieve the mp3 file from cache and play it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `reader.read()`

```
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
 const responsePromise = cache.match(request);
 responsePromise.then(result => {
    var reader = result.body.getReader();
    reader.read().then((result) => {
        const mimeType = 'audio/mpeg'
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result.value.buffer], {type: mimeType}))
        this.audio = new Audio(url);
        const playPromise = this.audio.play();
        playPromise.then(function() {
           console.log('success!')
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }.bind(this), false);
      }); 

 });
```

});